# How to use other's dependency from github packages in my own maven project

Tags: maven

Recently, I try to add a maven dependency from github packages and exactly do what the pages said to me. That [page](https://github.com/kaixindeken/TwTSSO/packages/302887) looks like this.

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ssotest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ssotest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.kaixindeken.TwTSSO</groupId>
        <artifactId>twtsso</artifactId>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and then I got this

```
Cannot resolve io.github.kaixindeken.TwTSSO:twtsso:0.3
```

Much appreciated if anybody can tell me why is that and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your Maven will automatically download all dependencies from Maven Central. There, the last (and only) version that currently exists is 0.2: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.kaixindeken/TwTSSO

You could probably use the instructions from the [README](https://github.com/kaixindeken/TwTSSO#3%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8-release-%E5%8C%85%E8%BF%9B%E8%A1%8C%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85) to install version 0.3 locally.